# Divs are pushed down in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div container which contains 6 divs. I need to layout the six divs in such a way that three of them are aligned to the left side and the rest aligned to right side. width of all divs is in percentage. The problem I am facing is when I resize the browser divs on the right side are pushed down. I'm using jquery:
Here is the css of one of the divs:

```
$("#titleDiv").css(
{
   background:"#eef0f8",width:"30%",height:"30px",float:"left",
  'margin-top':"25px",'margin-left':"10px",
  'padding-left':"3px",'padding-right':"2px"
});
```

This is the css of the container:

```
$("#container").css(
{
   'margin-top':"5px", position:"absolute",top:"135px"
});
```

Comment: instead of giant css string, why not just add a class?

Comment: @David, sure using a class is much better. But if each div has its own attributes, in this case a class will not be of any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a width to the #container div to stop the inner divs from moving down.